# Logging module is not working for Flask API on Apache

Tags: flask, apache2, flask-restful

I have **deployed FLASK API along with Apache 2.0 server on Windows**, and which is **working fine**.

Now I am in process of introducing the **logs on application level** with the help of Python logging module, which is also **working as expected when I run Flask alone without Apache**. But **it is not working along with Apache**.

I have 3 loggers to log the details for application restart, successful request and responses, and unsuccessful requests, error details and the responses. Everything works fine without Apache, so I am missing something or doing something wrong in the configuration level.

I have browsed for solution but couldn't get any solution material, I have already invested 3 to 4 days without any result.

Please throw some light on this, this is my first API deployment in production. Having limited knowledge in the production configurations.

### API structure

```
    daai_api
        -> apps
           -> customers
              - name_matching_program.py
              - routes.py  
           -> wsgi_scripts
              - customers.wsgi
           -  __init__.py               ----> this is where the logging configuration invoked
        -> logs
           - api_access
           - api_error
           - api_restart
        - .env
        - config.py
        - **logging.yml**
```

Am using the YAML file (logging.yml) for configuration which is listed below

```
##### logging.yml file #####

version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: true
formatters:
    standard:
        format: '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] - %(message)s'
    access:
        format: '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] - %(threadName)s - % 
        (message)s'
    error: 
        format: '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - [%(filename)s:%(funcName)s():%(lineno)d] - % 
        (threadName)s - %(message)s'
    
handlers:
    api_start_file_handler:
        class: logging.FileHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: standard
        filename: logs/api_restart/api_restart.log
        #filename: api_restart.log
        encoding: utf8
        
    access_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
        level: INFO
        formatter: access
        filename: logs/api_access/api_access.log
        #filename: access.log
        when: 'D'
        interval: 1
        backupCount: 30 
           
    error_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
        level: ERROR
        formatter: error
        filename: logs/api_error/api_error.log
        #filename: error.log
        when: 'D'
        interval: 1
        backupCount: 30
    
loggers:
    access_logger:
        level: INFO
        handlers: [access_file_handler]
        
    error_logger:
        level: ERROR
        handlers: [error_file_handler]
        
    restart_logger:
        level: DEBUG
        handlers: [api_start_file_handler]
```

Using the app factory to start the Flask application, and setting the logging configuration details in the ****init**.py** file

```
##### daai_api/apps/__init__.py #####

from flask import Flask
from apps.customers.routes import customer
from config import config
import yaml
import logging
from logging.config import dictConfig
import os

def create_app(apps_config='production'):

    logging_config = os.path.abspath('../daai_api/logging.yml')
    if os.path.exists(logging_config):
        with open(logging_config, 'r') as f:
            #lgconfig = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
            lgconfig = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
        dictConfig(lgconfig)
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[apps_config])
    app.register_blueprint(customer)
    
    
    logger = logging.getLogger('restart_logger')
    logger.info('App started as app factory...')

return app
```

The WSGI file of the API

```
##### customers.wsgi #####
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, 'D:\\DAAI\daai_api')

try:
    from apps import create_app                

except Exception as e:
    print('Import error: ', e)
    raise
    
application = create_app('production')
```

Apache configuration:

```
##### cutomers.conf #####
<VirtualHost *:1234>
    ServerName 12.345.678.900
    WSGIScriptAlias / D:/DAAI/daai_api/apps/wsgi_scripts/customers.wsgi
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    <Directory D:/DAAI/daai_api/apps>
        #WSGIProcessGroup D:/DAAI/daai_api/apps
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am not sure what information needs to be provided from Apache httpd.conf. Please reply if any specific information is required from httpd.conf.